# Use of malloc of a struct containing multiple elements

Tags: c, struct, malloc

What am I doing wrong here?

I have a QueueElement struct containing a char* text and a pointer to the next element, so obviously a linked list:

```
//QElement as in QueueElement
struct QElement {
    char* text;
    struct QElement* next;
};
typedef struct QElement QElement;
```

....

```
void enqueue (char* string){
QElement *new = (QElement *)malloc(sizeof(QElement)); 
//QElement cast is probably redundant but it doesn't hurt anyone
strcpy (new->text, string);

//some other stuff happening here, linking to other element in linked list, 
//but thats not of interest at the moment

}
```

....

If I try to enqueue a word in the main function, I keep getting segmentation faults and valgrind is telling me, that I'm doing something wrong when I'm using strcpy, so my malloc seems to be incorrect. How do I have to do it?

Comment: I know this is a C question, but even so it's generally not a good idea to use `new` as a variable name. This is a C++ keyword and will cause all kinds of problems if you ever try to compile your code as C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strdup(.)` recommended by other answers is non-standard. If you're not on a Unix platform it may not be available.

However the point is correct. You need to allocate memory to store your string.

Try:

```
const size_t sz=(strlen(string)+1)*sizeof(*string);//Space required. Including '\0' terminator.
new->text=malloc(sz);//space allocated.
if(new->text==NULL){//sz never 0 because +1.
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);//Allocation failed in non-error handled function.
}
memcpy(new->text,string,sz); //typically fastest way to copy!
```

Instead of `strdup(.)`.

My use of `sizeof(*string)` is actually unnecessary (as it is always 1) but the compiler will spot that and it's just good practice.

One day the world will move more uniformly to multi-byte characters and this code is ready for that glorious dawn!

Don't forget to `free(.)` when you've finished with the 'QElement'. 
You should probably write a function like this:

```
void QElementDestroy(QElement*const element){
    if(element==NULL){
        return;//Nothing to do!
    }
    free(element->text);//Needs NULL protection.
    free(element);//Does not need NULL protection. But we've done the test anyway!
    //NB: Order matters here. A lot.
}
```

And call it when you've finished with value returned by `enqueue(.)`.

If you want the string to 'out live' the element set `element->text=NULL` before calling destroy.
`free(NULL)` is required to do nothing and return normally.

**PS:** I think `strdup(.)` is a bit of a n00b trap. They take a while to get the hang of matching `malloc(.)` and `free(.)` and `strdup(.)` is a bit of a traitor because none of the other `str...` functions allocate space the caller is expected to `free(.)`. It's also non-standard.

Comment: Idea: `QElementDestroy()` itself should be tolerant of `QElementDestroy(NULL)` just like `free(NULL)` is OK.

Comment: @chux: Good idea. Always a good idea to make things that 'look' like library functions to act like their similars.

Answer (score 3):

in this code

```
strcpy (new->text, string);
```

`new->text` is not allocated memory. It might contain some garbage value, or some write protected memory address or even NULL. Passing that pointer to `strcpy()` will lead you to [Undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and as a side effect you may experience the segmentation fault.

You can make use of [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) or can allocate memory to `new->text` before `strcpy()`-ing to that pointer. Both the cases, you need to `free()` the allocated memory afterwards.

Also,

1. Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.
2. Check for the success of dynamic memory allocation [`malloc()`/ `calloc()`] before using the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are allocating the memory for structure variable only. You have to allocate the memory in the structure member.

```
 new->text=malloc(10);//for example
```

After the allocation of memory you can use the strcpy function.

Answer (score 1):

You have allocated the memory for `new`, but not for the `text` member variable.
Allocate the memory for `text` and execute the code.